# Loading Animation Starts On Pre ICS Devices But Will Not Start On Post ICS Devices

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm coming across an issue where the loading animation (5 sequential dots moving left to right) does not function in post ICS devices but works perfectly in pre ICS devices. I've attempted to replicate the same method of invoking the animation in both but it does not seem to be working.

Thank in advance,

Amani Swann

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();
        handler.setContext(this.getBaseContext());
        getImpVariablesForQuery();

        if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

            try {
                // updating layout initially has updating text with 1 dot in the
                // xml
                setContentView(R.layout.updating);
                // This image view has the updating text to be progressively
                // updated
                // with dots addition
                ImageView loading = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);

                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating1);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();

                ImageView loading2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);

                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating2);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading2.getBackground();

                tasks.execute("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31771876/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
                if (tasks.get() != null) {
                    stream = tasks.getInputStream();
                    Log.v("CfA", "here");

                } else if (tasks.get() == null) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.error);

                    // finish();
                    // finish();

                }

                handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

                Values = getContentValues();

            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update APN table in separate thread
            new TableUpdateRequestTask().execute("");

        } else {// ICS and later versions

            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {

                // updating layout initially has updating text with 1 dot in the
                // xml
                setContentView(R.layout.updating);
                // This image view has the updating text to be progressively
                // updated
                // with dots addition
                ImageView loading = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);

                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating1);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();

                ImageView loading2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);

                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating2);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading2.getBackground();


                setContentView(R.layout.updating);



                /*
                 * DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
                 * BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                 * InputStreamReader(in)); String strLine; while ((strLine =
                 * br.readLine()) != null) { // Print the content on the console
                 * System.out.println (strLine); in.close(); }
                 */

            //finish();
            new TableUpdateRequestTask().execute("");
            handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

            Values = getContentValues();
            showNotification();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

    private ContentValues getContentValues() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        nameArr = handler.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = handler.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = handler.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();

        portArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        count = handler.getCount();
        System.out.println("count" + count);
        values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
        values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
        values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo)));
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att)));
        }

        return values;
    }

    private void getImpVariablesForQuery() {

        // to get MDN
        Integer MDN = Integer.parseInt(tm.getSimOperator());
        Log.d("MDN", MDN.toString());
        mdn1 = MDN % 1234;
        Log.d("mdn1", mdn1.toString());
        mdn2 = MDN / 1234;
        Log.d("mdn2", mdn2.toString());
        // to retrieve ICCID number of the SIM

        String ICCID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();

        Log.d("ICCID", ICCID);

        long d = 1234;
        BigInteger divisor = BigInteger.valueOf(d);
        BigInteger bInteger = new BigInteger(ICCID);

        id = bInteger.divideAndRemainder(divisor);
        id1 = id[1];
        System.out.println("ICCID%1234 = " + id1);
        id2 = id[0];
        System.out.println("ICCID/1234 = " + id2);
        // Check for the Carrier Type
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            car = "TMO";
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            car = "ATT";
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public ContentValues generateTFConfig() throws IOException, SAXException,
            ParserConfigurationException {
        // Extract the IMSI from the TelephonyManager instance
        // String imsi = tm.getSubscriberId();
        String operator = tm.getSimOperator();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // Query the carrier table for the current data settings
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(APN_TABLE_URI, null, "current=?",
                new String[] { "1" }, null);
        values = copyRecordFields(c);
        // Copy the Simple Mobile settings into values
        /*
         * query the server for the data settings put the returned data settings
         * into values
         */

        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String Append_URL = "settingsquery?";
        String param1 = "mdn1=";
        String param2 = "&mdn2=";
        String param3 = "&car=";
        String param4 = "&id1=";
        String param5 = "&id2=";
        String URL = "";
        String parameters = param1 + mdn1 + param2 + mdn2 + param3 + car
                + param4 + id1 + param5 + id2;
        URL = Base_URL + Append_URL + parameters;
        Log.i("url...", URL);
        new NetworkTask().execute(URL);

        // if (handler.getQueryResult().equals("success")) { values.put("mmsc",
        // handler.getMMSCArr());

        // handler.getMmscProxyArr(); values.put("mcc",
        // getString(R.string.mcc));
        // if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
        // values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
        // values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo))); } else if
        // ((tm.getSimOperator()) .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
        // values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
        // values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att))); }

        // } else if (handler.getQueryResult().equals("no match")) {
        // showAlert("no match"); } else if
        // (handler.getQueryResult().equals("no plan")) { showAlert("no plan");
        // }

        return values;
    }

    /*
     * Insert a new APN entry into the system APN table Require an apn name, and
     * the apn address. More can be added. Return an id (_id) that is
     * automatically generated for the new apn entry.
     */
    public int InsertAPN() throws SecurityException {

        int id = -1;
        if (i < nameArr.size()) {
            for (i = 0; i < nameArr.size(); i++) {
                ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
                // values2 = values1;
                values2 = getValues();
                ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    Uri newRow = resolver.insert(APN_TABLE_URI, values2);
                    // System.out.println("values in insertAPN" + values1);
                    if (newRow != null) {
                        c = resolver.query(newRow, null, null, null, null);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Newly added APN:");
                        // TF Settings have been inserted
                        // Obtain the apn id
                        int idindex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                        c.moveToFirst();
                        id = c.getShort(idindex);

                        Log.d(TAG, "New ID: " + id
                                + ": Inserting new APN succeeded!");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                if (c != null)
                    c.close();
            }
        }
        return id;

    }

    public ContentValues getValues() {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
        values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
        values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo)));
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att)));
        }

        return values;

    }

    /*
     * Delete APN data where the indicated field has the values Entire table is
     * deleted if both field and value are null
     */
    private void DeleteAPNs(String field, String[] values)
            throws SecurityException {
        int c = 0;
        c = getContentResolver().delete(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null);
        if (c != 0) {
            String s = "APNs Deleted:\n";
            Log.d(TAG, s);

        }

    }

    /*
     * Return all column names stored in the string array
     */
    private String getAllColumnNames(String[] columnNames) {
        String s = "Column Names:\n";
        for (String t : columnNames) {
            s += t + ":\t";
        }
        return s + "\n";
    }

    /*
     * Copy all data associated with the 1st record Cursor c. Return a
     * ContentValues that contains all record data.
     */
    private ContentValues copyRecordFields(Cursor c) {
        if (c == null)
            return null;
        int row_cnt = c.getCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "Total # of records: " + row_cnt);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();//
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
            Log.d(TAG, getAllColumnNames(columnNames));
            String row = "";
            for (String columnIndex : columnNames) {
                int i = c.getColumnIndex(columnIndex);
                row += c.getString(i) + ":\t";
                // if (i>0)//Avoid copying the id field
                // id to be auto-generated upon record insertion
                values.put(columnIndex, c.getString(i));
            }
            row += "\n";
            Log.d(TAG, row);
            Log.d(TAG, "End Of Records");
        }
        return values;
    }

    // showAlert displays the text contained in message as an alert
    public void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        ConfigFinalActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showErrorAlert displays an alert with layout and a title
    private void showErrorAlert(int layoutRes, String title) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = ConfigFinalActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setTitle(title)
                .setView(inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null))
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.assisted_button),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
                                try {
                                    showNotification();
                                } catch (SAXException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showNotification starts the process of sending notifications to the bar
    // to assist the user in updating the data settings on ICS and later
    // versions of Android
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    void showNotification() throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        // handler.getQueryResponse();

        /*
         * String charset = "UTF-8"; String Append_URL = "settingsquery?";
         * String param1 = "mdn1="; String param2 = "&mdn2="; String param3 =
         * "&car="; String param4 = "&id1="; String param5 = "&id2="; String URL
         * = ""; String parameters = param1 + mdn1 + param2 + mdn2 + param3 +
         * car + param4 + id1 + param5 + id2; URL = Base_URL + Append_URL +
         * parameters; Log.i("url...", URL); new NetworkTask().execute(URL);
         */
        String field = getString(R.string.config_name_label);

        String value = Values.get("name").toString();
        int mId = 1;
        String title = "1 of " + UpdateActivity.TotalSteps + " (Update "
                + field + ":)";
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(value);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this,
                NotificationActivityForMultiProf.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(field, value);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotification = mBuilder.getNotification();
        mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mNotification);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mNotification != null) {
            outState.putString("NOTIFICATIONB", mNotification.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mXButton) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    // This thread performs the setting update and shows pseudo progress update
    private class TableUpdateRequestTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            int result = 0;

            try {
                result = updateTable();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }// Settings updated with this atomic call
            catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // The code below plays a ST Promo animation
            // prior to displaying update success or failure message
            for (int incr = 0; incr < 2; incr++) {
                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                // Invoke UI to change updating text to show 1 dot
                // And Increasing the level to reduce the amount of clipping and
                // slowly reveals the hand image
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full);

                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
            }
            if (result != -1)
                return "success";
            else
                return "failure";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Show updated screen if table was successfully updated
            // Or alert indicating settings are not updated
            if (result.equals("success")) {
                completeUpdate();
            } else
                setContentView(R.layout.error);

        }

        // Framework UI thread method corresponding to publishProgress call in
        // worker thread
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Call function to update image view
            setProgressImgView(progress[0], progress[1], progress[2],
                    progress[3], progress[4]);
        }

    }

    private int updateTable() throws IOException, SAXException,
            ParserConfigurationException {
        int insertResult = -1;// returned value if table is not properly updated
        try {
            ContentValues TFCarrierTableEntry = generateTFConfig();
            // ContentValues TFCarrierTableEntry2 = generateTFConfig();
            // Replace T-Mo Data settings if there is no SIM or SM/T-Mo SIM is
            // present
            if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                            .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {

                // delete all APNs before adding new APNs
                DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_tmo) });
                // Insert NET10 Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = InsertAPN();

            } else if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                            .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                // Delete all APNs before adding new APNs
                DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_att) });
                // Insert NET10 Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = InsertAPN();

            } else
                // non SM/ non T-Mo SIM
                showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_sm_dialog));
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            showErrorAlert(R.layout.assisted_setting,
                    getString(R.string.assited_title));
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return insertResult;
    }

    private void completeUpdate() {
        // Displaying final layout after pre-ICS automatic settings update
        setContentView(R.layout.completion);
        mXButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x_button);
        mXButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // This function return a cursor to the table holding the
    // the APN configurations (Carrier table)
    public Cursor getConfigTableCursor() {
        return getContentResolver()
                .query(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getnameArr() {

        return nameArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getApnArr() {

        return ApnArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMMSCArr() {

        return mmscArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMmscProxyArr() {

        return mmsproxyArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMmsPortArr() {

        return mmsportArr;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getProxyArr() {

        return proxyArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPortArr() {

        return portArr;
    }

    private void setProgressImgView(Integer imgViewId1, Integer imgViewId2,
            Integer imgViewId3, Integer imgViewId4, Integer imgViewId5) {
        // update image view with the updating dots
        // Reset view layout in case orientation while updating
        setContentView(R.layout.updating);
        mProgressImageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);
        mProgressImageview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);
        mProgressImageview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty3);
        mProgressImageview4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty4);
        mProgressImageview5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty5);
        mProgressImageview1.setImageResource(imgViewId1);
        mProgressImageview2.setImageResource(imgViewId2);
        mProgressImageview3.setImageResource(imgViewId3);
        mProgressImageview4.setImageResource(imgViewId4);
        mProgressImageview5.setImageResource(imgViewId5);
        // mLoadingCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty);

    }

    class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream> {
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "STDataSettings";
        private static final String TAG_RESULT = "success";
        private InputStream stream;

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bundle queryResults = null;

            String urlQueryString = params[0];

            try {
                stream = getQueryResults("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/646464/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return stream;
        }

        /*
         * Sends a query to server and gets back the parsed results in a bundle
         * urlQueryString - URL for calling the webservice
         */
        protected synchronized InputStream getQueryResults(String urlQueryString)
                throws IOException, SAXException, SSLException,
                SocketTimeoutException, Exception {
            // HttpsURLConnection https = null;
            Bundle queryResults = new Bundle();

            HttpsURLConnection https = null;
            String uri = urlQueryString;
            // URL urlo = new URL(urlQueryString);
            URL urlo = new URL(uri);

            https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();
            https.setConnectTimeout(50000); // 20 second timeout
            https.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            try {
                https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();
                // https.setConnectTimeout(20000); //20 second timeout
                // connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                // connection.connect();

                // xmlStream = new BufferedInputStream(https.getInputStream());

                if ("gzip".equals(https.getContentEncoding())) {
                    stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
                } else
                    stream = https.getInputStream();

                // stream = new BufferedInputStream(https.getInputStream());
                /*
                 * DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
                 * BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                 * InputStreamReader(in)); String strLine; while ((strLine =
                 * br.readLine()) != null) { // Print the content on the console
                 * System.out.println (strLine); in.close(); }
                 */
            } catch (SSLException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                // https.disconnect();
            }
            // String queryResult = handler.getQueryResponse(stream );
            String queryResult = null;
            queryResults.putString(TAG_RESULT, queryResult);
            /*
             * if (queryResult.equals("success")) {
             * queryResults.putString("Name", handler.getName());
             * queryResults.putString("APN", handler.getApn());
             * queryResults.putString("MMSC", handler.getMMSC());
             * queryResults.putString
             * ("Proxy_address",handler.getProxyAddress());
             * queryResults.putString("Proxy_Port",handler.getProxyPort());
             * queryResults
             * .putString("MMSC_Proxy_address",handler.getMMSCProxyAddress());
             * queryResults
             * .putString("MMSC_Proxy_address",handler.getMMSCProxyPort()); }
             */
            // XmlParserHandlerFinal handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();
            // handler.getQueryResponse(xmlStream );

            return stream;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() {
            return stream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {

        }
    }
}
```

updating1.xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:oneshot="false">    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_empty" android:duration="500" />    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_full" android:duration="500" />    
</animation-list>
```

Comment: Are the resources `R.drawable.updating1`, `R.drawable.updating2` & `R.id.loading_empty1` Ani GIFS?

Comment: XML/PNG (I updated my source above) : )

Comment: Ok. By post ICS device you mean Jelly Bean devices...ICS included?

Comment: Yes - I do (I should have been more specific)

Comment: is there any reason you dont want to call `loadingAnimation.start();` after each assignment?

Comment: It's working in the pre ICS section of my code - therefore I didn't see a reason to elsewhere - that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the developer documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame 
 The example shows a call to `start()` method of the animation.

```
ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);

rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
rocketAnimation.start(); // <--------- Does no harm to PRE ICS devices
```

If you are going to target various droid releases (JB included), why not call this method?

Comment: Well... That got the first two to blink! but I need them to blink sequentially one after the other : )

Comment: Is there a way to stall/stagger them that you know of?

Comment: Try forcing Anti-OneShot by calling `anim.setOneShot(false)`. Stall/stagger....not sure wat you mean by that put probably not. Actually I hardly ever use this method for animations. I preffer Gifs and CSS coz i always use webview for gui roles.

Comment: loadingAnimation.setOneShot(false); does not appear to perform the function I'm looking for - I'm attempting to load one icon, then the next, then the next.